# How to use tab name in this specific formula?

Tags: google-sheets

Looking at this formula...

```
=SUMIF('202302'!B1:B,"Sale",'202302'!F1:F)
```

... it pulls the sum (from another tab) of the numbers in column F if certain rows in column B has "Sale" (or "Fees", "Taxes", etc) in it.

See attached screenshot.
[image]

My question is how do I extract the tab names (ex. 202302) and use them in the formula so I don't have to keep *manually* adding them everytime. If not the tab names, maybe the values on A2, A3, etc since those are the tab names as well.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this in `Cell B2` of your `main` tab and drag it downside and side-ways

```
=SUMIF(indirect($A2&"!B:B"),B$1,indirect($A2&"!F:F"))
```